# laravel get one of each duplicate column

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent, laravel-mongodb

The structure of the table in the database is as follows:

| id | body | user_id | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | test1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | test1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | test2 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | test3 | 5 | 3 |

I want to get the first row from each `group_id` with Eloquent/DB Facade or MongoDB Query in Laravel with paginate:

##### For Example:

| id | body | user_id | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | test2 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | test3 | 5 | 3 |

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

for Mongodb use this aggregation

```
[
  {
    $sort:{
       group_id: 1,
       user_id:1
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'group_id': '$group_id'
      }, 
      'a': {
        '$first': '$$ROOT'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Eloquent's `GroupBy` as below, it will fetch the first record from the same group:

```php
DB::table('tablename')
    ->groupBy('group_id')
    ->get();
```